# Azure Function (C#, v1): Logging does not work properly

Tags: logging, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I implemented an Azure Function that is time triggered. It shall run e.g. every 15 minutes. But when I look into the logs from Application Settings I don't see every run despite the Azure Function actually runs every 15 minutes. Why is this happening?

Comment: What does this have to do with C# and what does v1 refer to?

Comment: The function is written in C#, and v1 is the version of Azure Function in use: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions. I added this information to give some context.

Comment: you're going to avoid so many issues upgrading to v2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What solved the issue for me was increasing the sampling rate (or disabling it completely) that can be adjusted via `host.json` (in this case for v1):

```
{
  "applicationInsights": {
    "sampling": {
      "isEnabled": true,
      "maxTelemetryItemsPerSecond" : 5
    }
  }
}
```

See also [Configure sampling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring#configure-sampling)